# In SvelteKit, after deleting the authToken, why is the exported data not updated when the new value of locals?.authUser on load function is undefined?

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

I'm experiencing an issue with the reactivity of `+layout.server.ts` and `+layout.svelte`. After deleting the `authToken` and passing it through the load function, I'm puzzled as to why the exported data isn't updated when the new value of `locals?.authUser` is undefined. I've verified on the server-side that it functions correctly and returns undefined for `authUser` in the terminal (`+layout.server.ts`). However, in CSR (`+layout.svelte`), after navigating to a new page, the data isn't updated; `authUser` is still displayed. It only updates if the browser is manually reloaded.

Any guidance on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

in +layout.server.ts

```
export const load = async ({ locals, depends, parent, cookies }: any) => {
    depends('authUser');

    const currentUser = locals?.authUser; //after delete authToken return undefined
    console.log('from main layout server', currentUser);

    return {
        currentUser: currentUser
    };
};
```

In the script of +layout.svelte, the data is not updated after navigating to a new page.

```
export let data;
    $: authUserMain = data.currentUser; //not updated
    $: {
        console.log('from layout svelte file', authUserMain);
        console.log('from layout svelte file data', $page.data); //the currentUser variable is not being updated
    }
```

Because `+layout.svelte` is present on all pages and isn't destroyed upon navigating to a new page.
Is the data not reactive?

Comment: How are you actually doing the delete?  If it's within a page, layout isn't going to update because it's intended to be lazy.  There is the `invalidate` functionality which is to give you better control.  https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-invalidate Try adding an `invalidate("authUser")` when it happens since you have the depends.  Relevant tutorial https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-dependencies

Comment: I tried to solve this problem by following your recommendation: watching url.pathname and triggering invalidate('authUser') on change. When attempting this, I noticed that adding a new variable url.pathname in +layout.server.ts and passing it to the data props made everything work correctly. Surprisingly, currentUser was updated even without using invalidate('authUser'). Quite a mystery! But problem was solved. Thank you for your recommendation!